# Is $ConPA \rightarrow \neg \Box \neg ConPA$ true in the standard model of arithmetic?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, peano-axioms

It can be shown (using Löb's theorem) that 
$$PA \nvdash ConPA \rightarrow \neg \Box \neg ConPA.$$

But what can be said about this sentence in the standard model of arithmetic $\mathcal{N} = (\mathbb{N}, 0, S, +, \cdot)$?

Do we also have $\mathcal{N} \nvDash ConPA \rightarrow \neg \Box \neg ConPA$?

And as a side question, I'm slightly confused by the assumed consistency of Peano arithmetic. Usually it is assumed that PA is consistent, but obviously by Gödel's second incompleteness theorem this cannot be proven within PA (if it is indeed the case). We also know that $\mathcal{N}$ is a model of PA. However, do we have $\mathcal{N} \vDash ConPA$?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well (under standard assumptions) we do indeed have $\mathcal{N}\models Con(PA)$; the problem is that there are *other* models of $PA$ which *don't* satisfy $Con(PA)$. Indeed, by the Completeness Theorem, the statement "$Con(PA)$ is independent of $PA$" is exactly equivalent to the statement "There are models of $PA$ in which $Con(PA)$ holds, and there are models in which it fails".

As to the sentence "$Con(PA)\implies \neg \Box\neg Con(PA)$" (I assume "$\Box$" means "is provable in $PA$", here), the answer to your question is "no": both the antecedent and the consequent are true in $\mathcal{N}$, so $\mathcal{N}$ does satisfy this sentence. The reason this sentence is not provable in $PA$ is that there can be models of $PA$ in which

- $PA$ is consistent, but
- $PA+Con(PA)$ is *not* consistent.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But why exactly is $\neg \Box \neg Con(PA)$ true in $\mathcal{N}$?

Comment: We generally assume a very strong property of $PA$ - that it is **sound**: anything provable in $PA$ is in fact true. (Note that this implies that $PA$ is consistent, but it's actually much stronger than that.) One consequence is that $PA$ does not prove "$PA$ is inconsistent," since, well, it's *not* inconsistent! So we have $\neg\Box\neg Con(PA)$ is true. But "true" is really just shorthand for "true in $\mathcal{N}$"! Note that we really do need to make an assumption here, that $PA$ is sound (well, that's overkill, but whatever); remember that model of $PA$ thinks it is the standard model.

Comment: If you aren't willing to make some assumptions about $PA$ beyond what $PA$ itself can prove, then of course we can't prove that the standard model satisfies $\neg \Box\neg Con(PA)$: for instance, since some models of $PA$ think $PA$ is inconsistent, in such models $\neg \Box\neg Con(PA)$ will be false!

Comment: @TomBombadil: When you try to argue that a sentence is **true** in a model, you have to argue in a formal system that can express these notions. In any reasonably strong set theory (like ZFC), you can prove that PA is consistent by showing that the natural numbers defined in your set theory satisfies the axioms of PA. The statement $\square \neg Con(PA)$ is "There does exist an object which codes a proof of the inconsistency of PA". Since PA can have non-standard models, PA cannot know if the objects it talks about are "real" natural numbers or not. On the other hand++

Comment: whatever set theory you have, it can prove one by one that no natural number codes a proof that PA is inconsistent and hence the sentence you referred to is actually true in the natural numbers (defined by your set theory).